# iOS NSUserDefaults Watching the change of values for a single key

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have the following code aiming to catch the event of a NSUserDefaults value changing for a particular key.

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self
                                    forKeyPath:SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE
                                       options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                       context:NULL];

 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *) keyPath ofObject:(id) object change:(NSDictionary *) change context:(void *) context
{NSLog (@"Changed for key %@", keyPath); }
```

But the observeValueForKeyPath is never getting called. I even tried replacing the SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE too with a string as mentioned in [Observing value changes to an NSUserDefaults key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633973/observing-value-changes-to-an-nsuserdefaults-key) but it has not helped.

Update:
I am changing the NSUserDefaults from a tabview. The above code to monitor changes is in a different tab of the same tabviewcontroller. In the tab where I monitor for the changes (the tab where above code exists), if I add a :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
//   NSLog(@"viewillappear");
NSUserDefaults *FUDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"The username obtained is: %@", [FUDefaults objectForKey:SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE]);
}
```

the updated NSUserDefaults value is obtained correctly, but the observeValueForKeyPath was never called.

Comment: Please post the code where you change the variable too

Comment: Also I take it you have `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver...` inside `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: NSUserDefaults *FDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[FDefaults setObject:userName.text forKey:SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: Yes, I have the addObserver... inside the viewDidLoad function only

Comment: After struggling with the same issue for one whole day: Make sure `SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE` does not contain any dots, since `keyPath` should not be namespaced in order to do KVO.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit: `viewDidUnload` is now deprecated, use `dealloc` instead to `removeObserver`

This should work perfectly, I have just tested here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self
                                            forKeyPath:@"SomeKey"
                                               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                               context:NULL];
    // Testing...
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    [defaults setObject:@"test" forKey:@"SomeKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"SomeKey"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *) keyPath ofObject:(id) object change:(NSDictionary *) change context:(void *) context
{
    if([keyPath isEqual:@"SomeKey"])
    {
       NSLog(@"SomeKey change: %@", change);
    }
}
```

Things you could test.

- Put a break point in viewDidUnload and make sure the view isn't disappearing on you (since you are changing `SomeKey` from another viewController) If this is the case then maybe move your register/de-register code into init/dealloc depending on how your VC works.
- Use explicit KeyPath like `@"SomeKey"` not a substitution like `SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE`

Comment: I just did a full phone reset (in the simulator) and did a build clean too. Now things are working fine. Thanks for your code. It works even with SOME_NSSTRING_VARIABLE

Comment: viewDidUnload is now deprecated, use dealloc instead to removeObserver

Comment: Yes things have changed now

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3 Version:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "keyPath", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "keyPath" {
        //Do something
    }
}

deinit {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "keyPath")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version:

```
func setUserDefaultsListener(){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "keyPath", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "keyPath" {
        //Do something
    }
}

deinit {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "keyPath")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 Version:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var keyPath: Int {
        return integer(forKey: "keyPath")
    }
}
```

HINT: make sure the `var` has exactly the same as the `keyPath`

and where you use the observer do:

```
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    observer = UserDefaults.standard.observe(\.keyPath, options: [.initial, .new], changeHandler: { (defaults, change) in
        //Do something
    })
}

deinit {
    observer?.invalidate()
}
```