# Web API client singleton vs Token in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager` to create a client for Web API. Basic stuff... `sharedInstance` as a singleton and methods for fetching specific data etc. So far so good. But there is one tricky part. User needs to login and in response he gets a uniqe token which will be stored in `NSUserDefaults`. So if there is token stored inside `NSUserDefaults` it's used to identify user on server and enable him to send request without need to login every time. This token has a long TTL but there is possibility that user will reinstall app or create new account so his token will be ereased.

My question is how to connect this `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass and token stored in `NSUserDefaults`? Is preferable to create a property in this client which will be checked when `shaedInstance` method is called? Or maybe check it manually every time I want to make a HTTP request?

Comment: Are you targeting ios6 or earlier, or only ios7 and up?

Comment: Only iOS 7 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html), subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager` and making a singleton is the way to go on iOS 7 and up:

> Developers targeting iOS 7 or Mac OS X 10.9 or later that deal extensively with a web service are encouraged to subclass `AFHTTPSessionManager`, providing a class method that returns a shared singleton object on which authentication and other configuration can be shared across the application.

Checking `NSUserDefaults` when `sharedInstance` is requested is probably not the proper way of doing it, because doing so precludes other parts of your code from storing a reference to the instance of singleton, say, in `viewDidLoad`, because if they do, the change of the token may go unnoticed.

Checking each request is a better option. You can place the checking code into a calculated `token` property on the `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass, and have it check `NSUserDefaults` value.

Finally, you could [set up an observer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784822/335858) on `NSUserDefaults`, watch for the change in the property that you need, and make the update automatically. The answer linked above explains how this can be done. In your situation, the code that sets up the observer would go into the constructor of your `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass, and the code that unregisters the observer would go into `dealloc` (the linked answer shows them in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload`).

Comment: Considering checking each request from computed property isn't it gonna kill the performance? Hitting every time `NSUserDefaults` is a optimal way? About solution with KVO... It's great but it's also obligatory to have an instance of `ASHTTPSessionManager` in every controller and I want to have access to it from `sharedInstance`.

Comment: @Cojoj `NSUserDefaults` caches data in memory, so it's not going to have any impact on performance, especially considering that the class sends a request across the network. As far as the KVO goes, you should be able to put the observer logic into the shared instance itself; all controllers would be able to use that shared instance, which keeps watching for `NSUserDefaults` changes.